# How to stack a pd.DataFrame until it becomes pd.Series?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have the following pd.DataFrame:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    data=[['dog', 'kg', 100, 241], ['cat', 'lbs', 300, 1]],
    columns=['animal', 'unit', 0, 1],
).set_index(['animal', 'unit'])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(*[['2019', '2018'], ['Apr', 'Oct']])))
```

and I would like to convert it a 2D matrix with no multilevel indexes on index or column:

```
pd.DataFrame(
    data=[
        ['dog', 'kg', 100, '2019', 'Apr'],
        ['dog', 'kg', 241, '2018', 'Oct'],
        ['cat', 'lbs', 300, '2019', 'Apr'],
        ['cat', 'lbs', 1, '2018', 'Oct']
    ],
    columns=['animal', 'unit', 'value', 'year', 'month']
)
```

To achieve this, I use `df.stack().stack()` -> this becomes a `pd.Series` and then I do `.reset_index()` on these series t convert to DataFrame.

My question is - how do I avoid the second (or multiple more) `stack()`?

Is there a way to stack a pd.DataFrame until it becomes a `pd.Series`?

Comment: use `melt` - `df.reset_index().melt(id_vars= ['animal', 'unit'])`  or `df.reset_index().melt(id_vars= df.index.names)`??

Comment: `df.stack(level=[0, 1])` ?

Comment: like @HenryEcker but generalized to any number of levels in columns `df.stack(list(range(df.columns.nlevels)))`, or if they have a name, then `df.stack(df.columns.name)` would work too

Comment: The melt worked magic. Thanks!  I did not know about this.